# Figure out which screen I am on in LibGdx

Tags: java, libgdx

I have a mouse click function so that the ball in my brick breaker game wouldn't start moving until the user clicks the screen, now this worked perfectly when the only screen was the level screen but after I added the menu screen once the user clicked the start button the ball would automatically start moving! 
Is there something I can add to my "if statement" which can check which screen I'm on such as "if (Gdx.input.isButtonPressed(Buttons.LEFT) && currentScreen == levelScreen) ? I tried getScreen() == levelScreen(), but since levelScreen isn't a variable it doensn't work, thanks!

```
if (Gdx.input.isButtonPressed(Buttons.LEFT)){
            pong.move = true;
        }
```

Comment: A better implementation would be to create an input processor that is only active while the "levelscreen" is shown.

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable to store current scene (currentSceneId for example) then change it as you switch between scenes and use it with the "if" statement

PS: If you are using scene2d and your level scene is an actor, add click listener to the level scene and do whatever you want your game to do

Answer (score 0):

The java `instanceof` operator is used to test whether the object is an instance of the specified type (class or subclass or interface).

```
if (Gdx.input.isButtonPressed(Buttons.LEFT) && getScreen() instanceof LevelScreen){
     pong.move = true;
}
```